# In chart.js how can I change the x axis on my line \chart from January-December to October-September? Basically, fiscal year instead of calendar year

Tags: time, overriding, chart.js

My line chart has multiple lines, one for each year. The points on each line have the correct date, but the chart starts at January instead of October and I have been unable to figure out how to make it start at October. Even though the point dates are correct, for example, 10/01/2014 or 9/30/2015, I have changed the formatted date years to all be the same year so all the lines will show in the same month.

Below are the generated chart and associated code.

[image: calendar chart]

```
        //process the data for all charts except dredge depth as it will function differently
        if (reportType !== "dredgedepth") {
            yValueKey = "DAY_VALUE";
            xValueKey = "Date";
            var CumulativeDayTotal = 0;
            var formattedDate, _date; code:
            var data, lineColor, monthName;
            var chartPlaceHolders = "";


            //loop through each year to build our objects needed for the chart
            $.each(jsonData.results, function (i, row) {
                data = row.dt;
                CumulativeDayTotal = 0
                yAxis = [];

                $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                    CumulativeDayTotal = parseInt(row[yValueKey]) + parseInt(CumulativeDayTotal);
                    //if not a cumulative report then set dates to be in the same year so chartjs will stack our lines
                    //instead of spreading across multiple years, this way it reads it as the same year so we can get functionality
                    formattedDate = row["DATE_F"];
                    if (nsData.myChartFormat !== "cumulative") {
                        formattedDate = moment(formattedDate).year(2016);
                    }
                    formattedDate = formatDate(formattedDate);
                    yAxis.push("{ y: " + CumulativeDayTotal + ", x: '" + formattedDate + "'}");
                });
                //create color for each new line/year
                lineColor = dynamicColors(i);

                chartPlaceHolders += '{label:"';

                if (nsData.myChartFormat === "fiscal") {
                    chartPlaceHolders += 'FY ';
                }

                chartPlaceHolders += row.year + '", data:[' + yAxis + '],' +
                    'fill: false,' +
                    'lineTension: 0.1,' +
                    'backgroundColor: "' + lineColor + '",' +
                    'borderColor: "' + lineColor + '",' +
                    'borderCapStyle: "butt",' +
                    'borderDash: [],' +
                    'borderDashOffset: 0.0,' +
                    'borderJoinStyle: "miter",' +
                    'pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",' +
                    'pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",' +
                    'pointBorderWidth: .2,' +
                    'pointHoverRadius: 1,' +
                    'pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",' +
                    'pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",' +
                    'pointHoverBorderWidth: 0,' +
                    'pointRadius: 2,' +
                    'pointHitRadius: .75,' +
                    'pointHitDetectionRadius : .75' +
               '},';

            });
        }
        //remove last comma from string
        chartPlaceHolders = chartPlaceHolders.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
        chartPlaceHolders = "[" + chartPlaceHolders + "]";

        var initFields = eval("(" + chartPlaceHolders + ")");

        //call newly created elements into a variable to pass along to the other functions
        var ctx = $("#primaryChart")[0].getContext("2d");

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: initFields
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: yAxisLabel
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        unit: 'month',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'month',
                            tooltipFormat: tooltipDateFormat,
                            displayFormats: {
                                millisecond: xAxisDateFormat,
                                second: xAxisDateFormat,
                                minute: xAxisDateFormat,
                                hour: xAxisDateFormat,
                                day: xAxisDateFormat,
                                week: xAxisDateFormat,
                                month: xAxisDateFormat,
                                quarter: xAxisDateFormat,
                                year: xAxisDateFormat
                            }
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: xAxisLabel
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you can show us a sample of your data source and your code we can probably help you, but without that we'd just be shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Guildencrantz This is my first post to stackoverflow. Can't seem to figure out how to attach an image of my chart or my code. I apologize. Can you advise?

Comment: Welcome! You shouldn't be including code as an image, you should format it inline. The [formatting reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) should help you out.

Comment: @Guildencrantz I added the code inline as best I could. Please let me know if this is enough to hopefully get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to get the fiscal years correct:

```
                $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                    CumulativeDayTotal = parseInt(row[yValueKey]) + parseInt(CumulativeDayTotal);
                    // MLP 12/22/16: If not a cumulative report then set dates to be in the same year (2016)
                    // so chartjs will stack lines instead of spreading across multiple years. This was Austin
                    // Martin's code. I assume he chose 2016 because it is a leap year and will include
                    // February 29 in case the user selects a date range that includes Feb 29.
                    formattedDate = row["DATE_F"];
                    if (nsData.myChartFormat !== "cumulative") {
                        formattedDate = moment(formattedDate).year(2016);
                    }
                    // MLP 12/22/16: If fiscal chart, set October 1 through December 31 to 2015
                    // so char will show October through September instead of January through December.
```

Here:

```
                    if (nsData.myChartFormat === "fiscal") {
                        if (moment(formattedDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD") >= "2016/10/01") {
                            formattedDate = moment(formattedDate).year(2015);
                        }
                    }




                    // MLP 12/13/16: format date to UTC MM/DD/YYYY using momentJS because the JavsScript
                    // Date function converts dates to the local time zone.
                    formattedDate = formatDateUtc(formattedDate);
                    yAxis.push("{ y: " + CumulativeDayTotal + ", x: '" + formattedDate + "'}");
                });
```